# An example of a unipotent matrix which is NOT upper triangular

Tags: matrices

Define::=  $I_n$ -- the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix.

Define::=  Nilpotent matrix -- an $n \times n$ real matrix $X$ such that $X^n = $ the zero matrix for some $n$ in the positive integers.

Define::= unipotent matrix $U$  -- $A - I$ which is nilpotent.

I'd like an example of a unipotent matrix which is **not** upper triangular

Comment: Silly examples: _lower_ triangular with 1's on the diagonal. And, then, in effect, everything between. Any matrix with all eigenvalues $1$ is unipotent, as follows from Jordan form.

Comment: Paul Garrett -- I'm using "From Groups to Geometry and Back" and unfortunately on p. 212  the author says that A is upper triangular, in the definition of unipotent p. 213 he uses A again saying that is a square matrix.  I'm assuming that the meaning of A did not change, if it did change then of course you are correct.   Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Paul Garrett -- I'm using "From Groups to Geometry and Back" and unfortunately on p. 212 the author says that A is upper triangular, in the definition of unipotent p. 213 he uses A again saying that is a square matrix. I'm assuming that the meaning of A did not change, if it did change then of course you are correct. Thanks for trying to help. – luysii 20 secs ago   edit

Comment: It is true that (square) upper-triangular matrices with 1's on the diagonal are unipotent. Also, (square) lower-triangular matrices with 1's on the diagonal. Also any (square) matrix $A$ whose characteristic poly is $(x-1)^n$, or, whose minimal poly is $(x-1)^m$ for some $m$. Either of the latter two has the property that any sufficiently large power of $(A-1)$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&1&1\end{array}\right]$$is unipotent because $(A-I)^2=0$ and $(A-I)$ is nilpotent where $I$ is the identity (or one can also argue that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(\lambda-1)^3$) whereas A is neither upper nor lower triangular.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is whether there can be a non-triangular nilpotent matrix. For example, consider a matrix $A = I_n + uv'$, where $u,v\in(\mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\})^n$ such that $\langle{u,v}\rangle = 0$. Since $u,v \neq 0$, $uv'$ and by extension $A$ are not necessarily triangle matrices.

Furthermore, $A$ is unipotent due to: $$(A - I_n)^n = (uv')^n = u(v'u)^{n-1}v' = 0$$